# EF Core 5 separate migrations into class library

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I try to separate EF Core migrations into a separate class library. I have an API project which references the class library with migrations.

I added

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

to both projects.

In the migrations class library, I have an extension method where I register `DbContext` into services:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddTMS(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var tmsConfiguration = configuration.GetSection("TMS");

    services.AddDbContext<TMSDbContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.UseSqlServer(tmsConfiguration.GetSection("ConnectionString").Value, sqlOpt =>
            {
                sqlOpt.MigrationsHistoryTable("_TMSMigrationsHistory");
                sqlOpt.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(TMSDbContext).AssemblyQualifiedName);
            });
        });

    return services;
}
```

This extension method is then called in `Startup.ConfigureServices` method. When I try to add initial migration into class library project via

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration --project .\TMS.csproj --startup-project ..\API\API.csproj --output-dir ./Database/Migrations --context TMSDbContext --verbose
```

then creating migration fails with this error:

> Using application service provider from Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.
> Found DbContext 'TMSDbContext'.
> Finding DbContext classes in the project...
> Found DbContext 'BOSDbContext'.
> Found DbContext 'BOSCommonDbContext'.
> Using context 'TMSDbContext'.
> Finding design-time services for provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'...
> Using design-time services from provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'.
> Finding design-time services referenced by assembly 'API'...
> Finding design-time services referenced by assembly 'TMS'...
> No referenced design-time services were found.
> Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly 'API'...
> No design-time services were found.
>
> System.IO.FileLoadException: The given assembly name or codebase was invalid.

I know that if I implement `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<T>` to create `DbContext` then it will work, but can it work without implementing this stupid interface?

Answer (score 1):

By the time I have found the solution. The right implmentation for AddTMS method looks like this:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddTMS(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var tmsConfiguration = configuration.GetSection("TMS");

    services.AddDbContext<TMSDbContext>(opt =>
    {
        opt.UseSqlServer(tmsConfiguration.GetSection("ConnectionString").Value, sqlOpt =>
        {
         sqlOpt.MigrationsHistoryTable("_TMSMigrationsHistory");
         sqlOpt.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(TMSDbContext).Assembly.FullName);
        });
    });

    return services;
}
```

See the difference in

```
sqlOpt.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(TMSDbContext).AssemblyQualifiedName);
```

vs.

```
sqlOpt.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(TMSDbContext).Assembly.FullName);
```

Comment: I think this is a helpful answer because the docs simply say you should pass "The name of the assembly" -- which is not clear enough.